# multiplying a $L^2(\Omega)$ function by a test-function

Tags: linear-pde

Suppose we have $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $v \in D(\Omega)$ a test-function.  If we multiply $f$ by $v$, the $(fv)$ function belongs to which space?

Comment: This not a meaningful question. There are all kinds of spaces to which the product belongs.

Comment: i mean the product fv belongs to $L^2(\Omega)$, or $L^1(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

$fv \in L^{2}$ because $v$ is bounded; $fv \in L^{1}$ by Holder's inequality: $\int |fv| \leq \sqrt {\int |f|^{2} } \sqrt {\int |v|^{2} }$.

Comment: can you please give me more details ?

Comment: @kayzo $\int|fv|^{2} \leq M\int |f|^{2}$ if $M$ is a bound for $|v|^{2}$.

Comment: its clear for me now, thank you!

Comment: Downvoting by revenge. Someone  downvoted several of my answers simultaneously.  If the answer is clear to you, you can consider upvoting/ approving the answer.